# Why aren't the Winter bash hats available in the meta site?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, winterbash

Why aren't the Winter bash hats available in the meta site? Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: Well we didn't opt in to the whole thing, so ...

Comment: Those winter bash hats are a _very_ strange thing...

Comment: Some people (including me) like strange things...

Comment: @StiffJokes Then maybe it's part of the strangeness that the hats aren't available on meta :)

Comment: I am inclined to call it as either a bug or an inconsistent feature.

Comment: many of the stackexchange sites seem to think tex.sx is an inconsistent feature.

Comment: Well, we cannot see the obtained hats. But I doubt if at least one of them is not available in a meta site. :-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Can you give an example of that attitude?

Comment: @marczellm -- i haven't got time to dig for citations now, but from the "behavior" of newbies on tex.sx who come from other established sites, it is clear that our "community practices" are rather uncommon.  for one thing, politeness and manners are the norm here; the practice regarding downvotes is one measurable example of that.

Comment: @marczellm: Another example of  odd things is a special typographical convention  to type with lowercase.  No offense. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), as per-site metas (or child metas) don't actually have an exclusive profile. :( The only exclusion is [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), since it covers network-wide meta-related content, and have individual user profiles separate from [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

As reference, see [Hat not showing on site meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211712/168244).